# dashboard not showing in 24hr chart

Tags: dashboard

The 24hr Hour Dashboard is not working - while other ranges (7 days, YTD etc). are working fine. I've tried clearing cache to no avail, and also refreshed statistics. Still not working. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is not working like what? Or not showing?

Have you check the data? Only successful orders (with Complete status) are now used to build the data. Invoiced Orders (with Processing status) are also shown in dashboard, as per Magento 1.7.0.2.

Have you check your code for 24h?

```
app\code\core\Mage\Reports\Model\Resource\Order\Collection.php
```

Have you check your Aggregated Data setting? Go to

```
System → Config → Sales → Sale → Dashboard And mark Use Aggregated Data (beta)="Yes"
```

Or you can read other possibilities here [Charts in Magento Admin dashboard displaying intermittently](http://support.createhosting.co.nz/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=62)